# How can I read posts from any random channels in Telegram?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I am trying to get all the messages from Telegram channel and display them in an ASP.NET web page but I didn't find any telegram API so far.
Is it even possible to read from any random channels in the Telegram?How and where can I find the proper Telegram APIs to do that for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since November 21, 2016, the bots allowed to getting New incoming channel post of any kind — text, photo, sticker, etc as Updates. Please refer to the [documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api-changelog#november-21-2016)

> Your bot can now get updates about posts in channels. Added new fields
> channel_post and edited_channel_post to Update.

I'm not sure if it's just for those bots that are channels admin but this is only things available now. If it didn't work you need to using Telegram API instead of Bot API.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use [telegram-cli](https://github.com/vysheng/tg/) which i did before. This github is discontinued and you should debug it by yourself to support channels.